# how to prevent f5 when cursor on URL

Tags: javascript, browser

Normally we can prevent a page refresh using F5 with `javascript` as below

```
if (keyCode == 116)
  event.preventDefault();
```

But I want to prevent the F5 refresh from working when the cursor is on the URL. This is not an application refresh, this is an in-page browser refresh.
When the cursor is on the URL and user presses the F5 key, the page will refresh. I need to prevent this.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent this to happen. Once the focus on the page is lost (i.e when you click in the URL bar) javascript won't receive keyboard events anymore.

However, you can display a message to the user to warn them they are about to leave the page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Your message here";
};
```

The user will be prompted the message when they try to leave the page (or refresh it) and have the option to leave or stay on the page. You can't completely stop the user from reloading, but you can make it sound real scary if they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check if mouse cursor if on URL, but you can check if your cursor is at position [0,0]

```
var cursorX;
var cursorY;
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    cursorX = e.pageX;
    cursorY = e.pageY;
}

$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
    if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 && (cursorX == 0 && cursorY == 0))
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

If cursorX and cursorY are equal to 0, then prevent your action

Comment: as you, we can get the position but, how to stop browser refresh

Comment: @Srikanth Edited my answer

Comment: your code will execute when cursor on our application, but i will keep mouse cursor on URL and click on f5 then page will refresh, its a browser functionality. i hope you got what i'm telling

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onmouseover** to keep track of when the mouse is over the URL and then you can use **onmouseout** to keep track of when it is off the URL. see the following example.

```
<a onmouseover="overIsTrue()"
   onmouseout="overIsFalse() href="http://www.yourpage.com">here</a>

//keep track of the mouse state
var overURL = false;

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

    // if the key is 116 and the mouseover is true
    if (event.keyCode === 116 && overURL) {

        // prevent default behaviour
        event.preventDefault();

        return false;
    }

});

//mouse over is true
function overIsTrue() {
    overURL = true;
}

//mouse over is false
function overIsFalse() {
    overURL = false;
}
```

Comment: i don't want mouseout or mouseover. When my mouse focus on URL and if i click F5 then normally page will refresh. This i want to prevent. its a browser functionality.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to disable F5 page refresh when the user is over the browser URL bar? or do you want to disable F5 when they are still on your page and the mouse is over the link?